# Same value being inserted into table with cursor

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to dynamically count the number of null values held in a table. So far I have this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(2000);
    FOR v AS CRS CURSOR FOR
        SELECT NAME
        FROM SESSION.TT1
    DO
        SET STMT = 'UPDATE SESSION.TT1 TT1
                        SET NULL_COUNT = (
                            SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT('''||v.NAME||''') NULL_COUNT
                            FROM Table1
                        )
                    WHERE TT1.COLUMN_NAME = '''||v.NAME||'''';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
    END FOR;
END
```

This runs fine, and does populate the temp table with data, but it updates every row with the same value (which is obviously incorrect).

Where have I gone wrong?

Note:

- The temporary table, TT1, was generated by another procedure, it contains two columns; NAME, and NULL_COUNT. All values in the NULL_COUNT column are undefined at this point, and the NAME column contains column names retrieved from syscolumns.
- I also tried removing the row and then inserting a new row rather than updating on the matched column name but this provides the same results.

Comment: Out of interest `NUMNULLS` in `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` will give you the number of NULL values in a column (as at the last RUNSTATS command)

Comment: @P.Vernon Ah yeah sorry, I should have mentioned that NUMNULLS isn't up to date and I don't have authorization to run the RUNSTATS command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes (or no quotes) around the column name, otherwise you are are simply counting a literal value, rather than the column...

```
DROP   TABLE TABLE1@
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(C INT)@
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(NULL),( NULL)@
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TT1(NAME VARCHAR(128), NULL_COUNT BIGINT)@
INSERT INTO SESSION.TT1 VALUES ('C',null)@

BEGIN
    DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(2000);
    FOR v AS CRS CURSOR FOR
        SELECT NAME
        FROM SESSION.TT1
    DO
        SET STMT = 'UPDATE SESSION.TT1 TT1
                        SET NULL_COUNT = (
                            SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT("'||v.NAME||'") NULL_COUNT
                            FROM TABLE1
                        )
                    WHERE TT1.NAME = '''||v.NAME||'''';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
    END FOR;
END
@
SELECT * FROM SESSION.TT1
@
NAME NULL_COUNT
---- ----------
 C             2
```

Comment: BTW, unless you are using `ORGANIZE BY COLUMN` tables, it would be more efficient to count the NULLs in all columns in one SELECT rather than one column at a time.. (assuming you want to run the above for more than one column in the same table).